# Querying ImportDefinition that falls on a certain date

Tags: soap-api

Im creating a weekly job to purge unneeded ImportDefinitions. We want to delete ImportDefinitions that are a months old. Is there an API(soap-api preferred) for querying ImportDefintions that are already a months old?

Answer (score 0):

According to the soap api docs:

> You can use date or datetime values, or date literals. The format for date and dateTime fields are different.

To use, you would construct a query like this:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate < THIS_MONTH
```

Docs on date literals are [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)